# How to upload a file to S3 from the /tmp folder in AWS Lambda using Node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda

I'm not really familiar with `nodejs`. So what I'm trying to do is to pipe out an object from `S3` into a `/tmp` folder, do some processing, and then put it back into another `S3` bucket.

But what's happening is that it will enter into the `uploadToS3()` function, but somehow it won't trigger the `fs.readFile`. So after logging the `inside uploadToS3 function`, it went into the `.then()` and log 'ends here'.

```js
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
const fs = require('fs');


const pipeObject = async() => {
    var params = { Bucket: 'testbucket', Key: 'test.txt' };
    var file = fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/test.txt');
    await s3.getObject(params).createReadStream().pipe(file);

}

const uploadToS3 = async() => {
  console.log('inside uploadToS3 function');
  fs.readFile('/tmp/test.txt', function (err, data) {
    console.log('inside readFile');   //code does not reach here
    if (err) { 
      throw err; 
      
    }

    var base64data = new Buffer(data, 'binary');

    var s3 = new AWS.S3();
    var s3upload = s3.putObject({
      Bucket: 'testbucket2',
      Key: 'output-test.txt',
      Body: base64data
    },function (resp) {
      console.log('Done');
    });

  });
}


exports.handler = async (event) => {
var params = { Bucket: 'testbucket', Key: 'test.txt' };

var file = fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/test.txt');

try{
    await pipeObject().then(response => {
        if (fs.existsSync('/tmp/test.txt')) {
            console.log('test.txt file exists.');
            uploadToS3().then(response => {
              console.log('ends here');
            });
        }
    });

    
    
    
}catch(err){
    console.log(err);
}

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should stick to using `await` or `.then` instead of trying to use both.

Since your handler is already `async` you might aswell use `await`.

You should defintely read up about [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and the [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

I've modified your code below with the following changes: (not tested).

I've changed your `uploadToS3` function so that it returns a `Promise`.

I've changed your handler function so that it no longer does an `await` and `.then`.

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
const fs = require('fs');

const pipeObject = async () => {
    var params = { Bucket: 'testbucket', Key: 'test.txt' };
    var file = fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/test.txt');
    await s3.getObject(params).createReadStream().pipe(file);
}

const uploadToS3 = async () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log('inside uploadToS3 function');
        fs.readFile('/tmp/test.txt', function (err, data) {
            console.log('inside readFile');   //code does not reach here
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
                return;
            }

            var base64data = new Buffer(data, 'binary');

            var s3 = new AWS.S3();
            var s3upload = s3.putObject({
                Bucket: 'testbucket2',
                Key: 'output-test.txt',
                Body: base64data
            }, function (resp) {
                console.log('Done');
                resolve();
            });
        });
    });
}


exports.handler = async (event) => {
    var params = { Bucket: 'testbucket', Key: 'test.txt' };

    var file = fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/test.txt');

    try {
        await pipeObject();

        if (fs.existsSync('/tmp/test.txt')) {
            console.log('test.txt file exists.');
            await uploadToS3();
            console.log('ends here');
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

Comment: the output file seems to be empty, but that's likely a seperate issue. This does solve my issue above. Thanks!